# SQL How to average two fields formed by a Case Statement

Tags: sql, case, calculation

Here is my query.  I have two recommenders with their own ranking.  I need to convert the rank into a number using the CASE statement and then average both numbers.  When I run the query I get "Invalid column name errors".  If I comment out the averageScore field, the CASE statement works as expected.

```
 select 
    (select [name] from [user] where ([id] = rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[user])) as [Name - Reviewer 1], 
    (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) as [Recommendation - Reviewer 1], 
    (select [name] from [user] where ([id] = rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[user])) as [Name - Reviewer 2], 
    (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) as [Recommendation - Reviewer 2], 
    
 --converting reviewer 1 scores
    (CASE WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'High Recommend' Then 3
     WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Recommmend' Then 2
     WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Low Recommend' Then 1
     WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Not Recommended' Then 0
 ELSE 111
 END) AS [Reviewer_1_Score],
 --converting reviewer 2 scores
    (CASE WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'High Recommend' Then 3
     WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Recommmend' Then 2
     WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Low Recommend' Then 1
     WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Not Recommended' Then 0
 ELSE 222
 END) AS [Reviewer_2_Score],
 --average both scores
    (([Reviewer_1_Score] + [Reviewer_2_Score])/2) as [AvgerageScore]
 
 from [application] a
 inner join [person] p on (p.[id] = a.[person])
 left outer join [lookup.round] r on (r.[id] = a.[round])
 left outer join [form.response] rf_reverse_d1b6_1 on (rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[record] = a.[id]) 
 and rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[user] In (select u1.[id] from [user] u1 where (select [value] from dbo.getFieldTopTable(u1.[id], 'user_panelist_number')) = 1)
 left outer join [form.response] rf_reverse_d1b6_2 on (rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[record] = a.[id])
 and rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[user] In (select u2.[id] from [user] u2 where (select [value] from dbo.getFieldTopTable(u2.[id], 'user_panelist_number')) = 2)
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using MS SQL based on your Syntax. In that case you can't reference a [column_alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in another column:

> column_alias can be used in an ORDER BY clause. However, it cannot be
> used in a WHERE, GROUP BY, or HAVING clause. If the query expression
> is part of a DECLARE CURSOR statement, column_alias cannot be used in
> the FOR UPDATE clause.

I think it's relatively easy to work around this with an [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
WITH data_table AS
(
     select 
        (select [name] from [user] where ([id] = rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[user])) as [Name - Reviewer 1], 
        (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) as [Recommendation - Reviewer 1], 
        (select [name] from [user] where ([id] = rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[user])) as [Name - Reviewer 2], 
        (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) as [Recommendation - Reviewer 2],   
     --converting reviewer 1 scores
        (CASE WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'High Recommend' Then 3
         WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Recommmend' Then 2
         WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Low Recommend' Then 1
         WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Not Recommended' Then 0
     ELSE 111
     END) AS [Reviewer_1_Score],
     --converting reviewer 2 scores
        (CASE WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'High Recommend' Then 3
         WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Recommmend' Then 2
         WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Low Recommend' Then 1
         WHEN (select [value] from dbo.getFormResponseTable(rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[id], 'nsf_app_scr_recommendtion')) = 'Not Recommended' Then 0
     ELSE 222
     END) AS [Reviewer_2_Score]
     from [application] a
     inner join [person] p on (p.[id] = a.[person])
     left outer join [lookup.round] r on (r.[id] = a.[round])
     left outer join [form.response] rf_reverse_d1b6_1 on (rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[record] = a.[id]) 
     and rf_reverse_d1b6_1.[user] In (select u1.[id] from [user] u1 where (select [value] from dbo.getFieldTopTable(u1.[id], 'user_panelist_number')) = 1)
     left outer join [form.response] rf_reverse_d1b6_2 on (rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[record] = a.[id])
     and rf_reverse_d1b6_2.[user] In (select u2.[id] from [user] u2 where (select [value] from dbo.getFieldTopTable(u2.[id], 'user_panelist_number')) = 2)
)
SELECT *
 --average both scores
,(([Reviewer_1_Score] + [Reviewer_2_Score])/2) as [AvgerageScore]
FROM data_table
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I have heard I would need a CTE, but I was never successful in the correct syntax.  This will work!!